# How to send image to Flask server from curl request

Tags: python, curl, flask, request, python-imaging-library

I want to send an image by curl to flask server, i am trying this curl command 
`curl -X POST -F file=image.jpg "http://127.0.0.1:5000/"`
 but it did not work by the way on the server side i handle the image by this code 
`image = Image.open(request.files['file'])` i am trying to read the image using PIL 
Is there anyway to do this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You shouldn't upload an image using GET. You should use POST.

Comment: @DavidSimic, thanks man, i was using POST and it did not work too, its a typo, ill fix it

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
curl -F "file=@image.jpg" http://localhost:5000/
```

The '@' is important, otherwise you end up with an http error 400 (server could not understand request). I've also dropped the "-X POST" bit as it's unnecessary.

My flask view:

```
from PIL import Image

@app.route("/", methods=["POST"])
def home():
    img = Image.open(request.files['file'])
    return 'Success!'
```

Comment: yes thank you my friend, i needed the @ sign, plus i needed to seek the buffer on the server side

Comment: @Ramahi.Amer, you're welcome, glad I could help! Please do accept the answer if you found it resolved the main question.

Comment: yes sure, I'm sorry my friend for the late acceptance, and thanks again